# How to connect to WiFi on 17.10?

Tags: wireless

I'm not familiar with Ubuntu, or Linux in general. I'm trying to use it as a temporary OS until I can find my Windows 7 CD. I'm having issues connecting to wifi, everything I find online about it says I need some external wifi adapter. I'm 100-200 feet away from my router, so Ethernet isn't an option (connecting from another house, not stealing someone's wifi).

Comment: 100-200 ft?? that's a long way for wifi. I would recommend a wifi repeater or move the router to a more centralized location.

Comment: I'm able to connect from other devices, I just can't find the network while using Ubuntu.

Comment: Here's your Windows 7 CD: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/where-can-i-download-windows-7-iso-i-have-a/7d964b05-2be9-4800-bc7f-3ca30356fc3d?auth=1 and if you need help you may ask at superuser.com

Comment: I'd download the ISO, but it would take a full day to do and wouldn't be able to use wifi on any other device the entire time.